# How to map non-primitive members to bytes/JSON with NPoco?

Tags: mapping, npoco

Say I have an object:

```
class Person {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public Address HomeAddress {get; set;};
}
class Address {
    public string Street {get; set;}
    public string City {get; set;}
}
```

I want/need the above object to be mapped to a single column named `Person` which has a column named `HomeAddress` whose content is a JSON (or some custom binary serialization).

How do I tell NPoco Database object to use such mapping?

Answer (score 0):

You would use the [SerializedColumn] attribute on the HomeAddress property of the Person class.  This will serialize/deserialize json text that is stored in the column.